# Design ideas for crafts.SE

Tags: discussion

Arts and Crafts is (probably) a week away from graduation.

We need to start coming up with ideas for site design. (similarly to [another site's post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321/design-ideas-for-gardening-stackexchange-com))

What should logos, upvote/downvote, color, and header and background images be once we are out of graduation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is way too early to discuss this.

Answer (score 9):

Um... you're gettting ***way*** ahead of the process.

There are four-ish steps to graduation.

We're currently in **private beta**, a week away from **PUBLIC BETA**, not "graduating". This is the equivalent of moving from kindergarten to first grade.

Graduation is a huge step and requires a lot of work. First, it requires that we spend at least thee months in public beta and we meet or exceed [all of these metrics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518/arts-and-crafts). Many sites stay in public beta (or just beta) for over a year before being made a full site (removal of the beta text) and even then have to wait months for a site design.

To make it even worse, some sites will never leave the beta phase, generally due to low usership and will never get a site design.

Note that the terminology for all of this has been in discussion on Meta Stack Exchange and is likely to change in the future.

So, we aren't getting a site design any time soon. Sorry.

Comment: The other thing to mention is that, when the time comes, we don't ultimately get the decision of what the site is going to look like. While they would value our input it is up to SE to finalize the design for the site.